# Error en código no deja cargar correctamente mi página

Tags: php, imagen

Mi problema es el siguiente, hay algo mal donde empieza `p-item-bnr` hasta donde empieza `p-item-img`
La idea es mostrar un banner que haya subido cada usuario, por detrás de la imagen principal `item-img`, dentro de un cuadro blanco

La sección de la imagen principal funciona correctamente, pero con el banner de atrás hace que la pagina no cargue por completo, por eso identifico el problema ahí.

```
   <div class=p-item-bnr">
                        <?php 
                        if(file_exists('uploads/vendor_banner_image/banner_'.$vendor_id.'.jpg')){
                        <div class="vendor_cover_img" style="background-image: url(<?php echo base_url();?>uploads/vendor_banner_image/banner_<?php echo $vendor_id;?>.jpg"></div>
                <div class="p-item-img">
                    <?php
                    if(!file_exists('uploads/vendor_logo_image/logo_'.$row['vendor_id'].'.png')){
                    ?>
                    <img  class="image_delay" src="<?php echo img_loading(); ?>" data-src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>uploads/vendor_logo_image/default.jpg" alt="">  
                    <?php
```

Answer (score 2):

Tus etiquetas de apertura/cierre de PHP están mal colocadas. Fijate en esto:

```
<div class=p-item-bnr">
<?php 
if(file_exists('uploads/vendor_banner_image/banner_'.$vendor_id.'.jpg')){
//aquí deberías cerrar las etiquetas de PHP porque empiezas un bloque html.
//luego, aquí deberías poner:
?>
//y ya continuas
<div class="vendor_cover_img" style="background-image: url(<?php echo 
...
```

Comment: Gracias, eso solucionó el tema de que no cargaba! No me había dado cuenta. Pero aparentemente la dirección de la que obtiene la imagen es la equivocada y no funciona bien Jajaja. Muchas gracias!